# Power Query M formula language foreign key checking

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am currently using the Power BI Power Query Editor writing queries using the Power Query M formula language. I currently have two tables named `employee` and `business`. Each row of the `employee` table has a `business_id` that connects to a row of the `business` table. I want to run a `Table.SelectRows` function to include only the rows where `employee.business_id = business.id`.

This is what I have so far:

```
let
    Source = MySQL.Database(<DATABASE>, "business_database", [ReturnSingleDatabase=true, CreateNavigationProperties=false]),
    business_database_employee_all = Source{[Schema="business_database",Item="employee"]}[Data],
    employee_included = . . . Return all rows from employee where employee.business_id = business.id . . .
in
    employee_included
```

Any sort of help with this one would be appreciated! I'm pretty set on using `Table.SelectRows` but I'm down to utilize better functions if it's recommended!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to filter the employee table so that it only shows rows where there is a match in the business_id field to the business table

the best way is to merge the business table into the employee table, matching the business_id field, with inner join

```
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"PriorStepNameinEmployeeTable",{"business_id"},business,{"business_id"},"business",JoinKind.Inner)
```

another way

```
#"Select" = Table.SelectRows(#"PriorStepNameinEmployeeTable", each Table.Contains(business_table,_,{"business_id"}))
```

Comment: This is definitely a solution! However, a merge such as this is very memory and storage intensive. Isn't there a solution using Table.SelectRows that I could use instead?

Comment: edited to provide Table.SelectRows method. No idea which is less intensive

Comment: did this work for you?

Comment: It did, thanks so much!